# Is there an option to export data from Palantir Foundry to Salesforce without using third party connectors

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

How can we export data from Palantir Foundry to Salesforce ? We would like to avoid third party connectors, so please suggest any viable solution using the inbuilt connectors in Foundry.

Thanks

The current Salesforce connector in Foundry provides only bulk import. Usually JDBC connectors have options to export but looks like it's not compatible with Salesforce

Comment: did you check https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-connection/webhooks-reference/#salesforce

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this would work with a Data Connection export task, such as what's described in the [Kafka docs](https://proper-raindrop.palantirfoundry.com/docs/foundry/streaming-sources/kafka/#export-data-to-kafka), but you'd need to contact Palantir directly to learn more about whether that's possible for Salesforce or JDBC sources in general.

One thing you could do is use [Python External Transforms](https://proper-raindrop.palantirfoundry.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms/) to write data to the Salesforce API. That would let you write whatever code you needed to collect the data in Foundry and sync it to Salesforce. You could also schedule those transforms to run just as you would with any other build. That said, I don't know enough about Salesforce to say whether there's an endpoint suitable to your needs.